# How to stream video and audio from one Raspberry Pi to another Raspberry Pi

Tags: streaming-video

I used [this](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2013/06/how-to-stream-video-and-audio-from-a-raspberry-pi-with-no-latency/) to stream video and audio from Raspberry Pi to my laptop.It worked fine.
now I need to stream audio and video from one Raspberry Pi to another Raspberry Pi. when I used the code that I run on my computer, on the second Raspberry Pi, nothing show. how can I show streamed video on the second Raspberry Pi?

**EDITE :**

I'm sorry for lack of informations. I run the following codes in terminal.

on my first Raspberry Pi I used :

for video streaming :

```
raspivid -t 999999 -w 1080 -h 720 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | \
gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 \
! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=serverIp port=5000
```

for audio streaming :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc device=plughw:Set \
! mulawenc ! rtppcmupay ! udpsink host=clientIp port=5001 sync=false
```

and on laptop i used :

to receive the video on my laptop:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=serverIp port=5000 \
! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

to receive the audio on my laptop:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5001 caps="application/x-rtp" \
! queue ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

now I need to receive streamed video and audio on the second Raspberry Pi.but when I used :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=serverIp port=5000 \
! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

It run fine, but nothing show.

both of Raspberry Pis are in the same network. and I have ping of each other.

Comment: What code did you use? Are the 2 Pi's om the same network? How are they connected? Please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: Can you write the code that you executed from your computer's command line?

Comment: I've editted the question